# How do I specify a shutdown script to run when a spot instance is shutting down?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is the best way to check if my instance is shutting down to poll `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time` every 5 seconds?

Google cloud allows me to specify a shutdown script for termination
`gcloud compute instances create example-instance     --metadata-from-file shutdown-script=examples/scripts/install.sh`

Does AWS have something similar by now?

Comment: No. AWS doesn't have a callback script to call when a spot is marked for termination. Polling every 5 seconds is the most common way. I early days, even this `termination-time` was not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. AWS doesn't have a callback script to call when a spot is marked for termination. Polling every 5 seconds is the most common way. In early days, even this `termination-time` was not available.

Another option is to check CloudTrail. It will receive a `TerminateInstances` for a future time (up to 2 minutes) for spot instances. Only issue is Cloudtrail is not in real time. It may be delayed by few seconds. If you are averse to continuous polling, I suggest sending CloudTrail `TerminateInstances` events to CloudWatch or integrate with Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article that discusses detecting AWS spot instance termination. This might help you with methods to detect shutdown in different scenarios.

[Handling AWS Spot Instance Termination Notices](https://blog.fugue.co/2015-01-06-spot-termination-notices.html)